# error: unmappable character for encoding UTF-8 for databinding

Tags: java, android

I am getting such an error, I changed uf8 I tried everything that is general What is this problem?

```
    app\build\generated\data_binding_base_class_source_out\debug\dataBindingGenBaseClassesDebug\out\com\cd\statussaver\databinding\ItemsFileViewBinding.java:23: error: unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
  public final ImageView iv�mage;
```

---

```
 protected ItemsFileViewBinding(Object _bindingComponent, View _root, int _localFieldCount,
  ImageView ivPlay, ImageView iv�mage, RelativeLayout rlMain, TextView tvFileName) {
super(_bindingComponent, _root, _localFieldCount);
this.ivPlay = ivPlay;
this.iv�mage = iv�mage;
this.rlMain = rlMain;
this.tvFileName = tvFileName;
```

Comment: What do you want? How did you get non-Latin symbols? Can you edit them manually?

Comment: I fix it but it gives the same error again.

Comment: Could you write an example, how did you fix it? Currently I see that you have non-Latin symbols.

Comment: Also, did you change an encoding in lower right angle od the IDE? https://imgur.com/a/h74cftn.

Comment: I tried but the problem is still not solved

Comment: Can you write an example? https://imgur.com/a/Uv6O9GS

Answer (score 1):

Let me do some guesswork.

In the editor where you wrote the code (and where you can read the text), what's the encoding that this editor uses? Or, open your java source in Notepad++, make sure that everything is readable, and look at the status line - does it say "UTF-8"? Probably not. I guess it's some 8-bit encoding like ISO-8859-nn or Windows CPnnnn.

And when compiling with your build framework (maven, gradle, javac, whatever), did you specify that very same encoding to be assumed for your source files? Probably not, as the error message says that it failed reading the source file as UTF-8 - here I see that the compiler assumed UTF-8 encoding.

From your name, I guess your computer might be localized for Turkish, where there is a special uppercase I with a dot that might cause the encoding troubles.

If you stay within the ASCII character set, you'll never experience these encoding troubles, but also never detect encoding mis-configurations.

To solve the problem, I see two possibilities:

- Transcode all your source files from their current encoding to UTF-8, configure your source code editors to use this encoding, and have the build framework assume UTF-8 (you probably have that third part already done).
- Find out the encoding that your source files really use, and configure that build framework to assume that encoding for the source files.

As all the industry is moving towards UTF-8, I'd recommend to go through the pain of the first possibility.

Comment: @HuseyinÖZDEMİR Please [edit] the question to add any essential infirmation. Do not post images of code or links to code. Post [mre]